# MySQLi update query not working - no errors?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why on earth the query below isn't working. Basically it checks if a checkbox is checked, if it is the checkboxes relating variable and therefore mysql record is set to 1. If the checkbox isn't checked its set to 0. I've added multiple different troubleshooting and error reporting snippets - no errors. Yet no success? This is driving me mad. Any advice is warmly welcomed! Thank you.

```
if(isset($_POST['updateUser'])){

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['host'], 
                         $config['user'], 
                         $config['pass'], 
                         $config['db']);

foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $check[$k] = isset($_POST[$k]) ? 1 : 0;
} 

$query = "UPDATE users_permissions SET editComments = ?, 
                                       editTopics = ?, 
                                       editArticles = ?, 
                                       autoApprove = ?, 
                                       allowArticleMod = ?, 
                                       courseAuthor = ?, 
                                       seeFinance = ?, 
                                       editUsers = ?, 
                                       editUsersPermissions = ?, 
                                       editSuperUsers = ?,
                                       editWL = ?
                                   WHERE 
                                       userid = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiiiiiii',                                                                                         

                                  $check['editComments'],
                                  $check['editTopics'],
                                  $check['editArticles'],
                                  $check['autoApprove'],
                                  $check['allowArticleMod'],
                                  $check['courseAuthor'],
                                  $check['seeFinance'],
                                  $check['editUsers'],
                                  $check['editUsersPermissions'],
                                  $check['editSuperUsers'],
                                  $check['editWL'],
                                  $profileData['userid']);
                                  $profileData['userid']);

$stmt->execute();

}
```

UPDATED: Changes made to code to reflect suggestion made by @Floris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but those if-blocks hurt my eyes. I know it's not really "the" answer but you should  do this instead:

```
$checks = [];
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $checks[$k] = isset($_POST[$k]) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Now you have an array called `$checks` which has all the `$_POST` keys as you had before with a 0/1 value depending on whether it was set, and you skip a whole bunch of ugly code! Yay! Now, just replace the `bind_param` vars with $check vars.

EDIT - More code, with comments:

```
//Go through each variable in the $_POST array, using "$k" to refer to the key and "$v" to the value,
//So, $_POST["editComments"] = "foo" would have $k = "editComments" and $v = "foo"
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    //This is a shorthand if-statement which basically means: if isset($_POST[$k]) == true, $checks[$k] = 1. Else, $checks[$k] = 0.
    $checks[$k] = isset($_POST[$k]) ? 1 : 0;
}

//Nothing new here
$query = "UPDATE users_permissions SET editComments = ?, 
                                   editTopics = ?, 
                                   editArticles = ?, 
                                   autoApprove = ?, 
                                   allowArticleMod = ?, 
                                   courseAuthor = ?, 
                                   seeFinance = ?, 
                                   editUsers = ?, 
                                   editUsersPermissions = ?, 
                                   editSuperUsers = ?,
                                   editWL = ?
                               WHERE 
                                   userid = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

//So here's how to bind the $checks variables:
$stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiiiiiii', $checks["editComments"],
                                  $checks["editTopics"], //and so on
                                  $editArticles,
                                  $autoApprove,
                                  $allowArticleMod,
                                  $courseAuthor,
                                  $seeFinance,
                                  $editUsers,
                                  $editUsersPermissions,
                                  $editSuperUsers,
                                  $editWL,
                                  $profileData['userid']);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I knew there would be an easier way of doing it :) Thanks for the useful insight. I'm okay with PHP, but not great! What's with the $k and $v? Am I missing something obvious? And how would I then use them afterwards in the prepared statement? Like this: $stmt->bind_param('i', $checks['editComments']) ?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to +1 but I'm really grateful for the explanation! I've learnt something tonight :) Doesn't answer the question but it does make an improvement. Thanks again.

Comment: On that note, actually, your code *should* work. So no errors are being spit out? Have you tried `if(!$stmt->execute()) { echo $mysqli->error() }`?

Comment: I should state I'm executing two queries in one submission. The first query works, the second doesn't: http://pastie.org/8559504

Comment: Have you tried doing `$stmt->close()` after the first query has been executed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43381/discussion-between-mmcdonald-and-floris)